# Will Minecraft LAN with friend work if both have same mods installed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I was wondering, if both me and my friend have the same mods and same versions of mods installed can we both play multiplayer locally?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you have to have *exactly* the same mods, with all the exact same version numbers and configuration, except for some mods that are client-side only (e.g. minimaps, Optifine, MAtmos, etc.) which don't need to be the same or even present on both sides.

The best way to test this isn't to check every mod you have — the easiest way is to just try. Assuming you're using Forge to install Minecraft mods, any mismatch with the hosting player's Minecraft mods will be detected by Forge, and it will refuse their connection with a message telling them what they're missing or need to get rid of before trying to connect again.

Comment: Also remember that mismatched block IDs are also fine, the client will adjust. But numerical IDs (for before the named-id-system was implemented) when used have to match the server's ID tables.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to. I think as long as all the players on the LAN have the same updates and mods they would be able to play together. But if one player has update 1.6 and the other had 1.5 it won't work.

Maybe check out this youtube video I found?

Answer (score -2):

It will work if you use a program such as Hamachi--or even better Tunngle. Hope that helps...

Comment: Would you mind changing your name?

Comment: Why does that matter?